# How does sed's P command work?

Tags: sed

The sed's document states

> P
>
> Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space.

I did some experiment and trying to understand it. Below is my testing.

```
root:[~]# seq 3 | sed -n '/2/{iline1\nline2;P}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
root:[~]#
```

Here `-n` disables the auto-printing of the pattern space. `/2/` matches the second line, which has the content `2`. So when the second line has been matched, the pattern space has the content `2`. The `i` command inserts `line1\nline2` and a newline character to the beginning of the pattern space. So the pattern space should have the content `line1\nline2\n2`. Now the `P` command *print up to the first new line*, so `line1` should be printed and should be the result of the whole command. Is my understanding correct? Why the error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `i` command does not insert anything into the pattern space. It writes its text to standard output.

Here's a better example:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
$ sed -n 'N;P' file
line 1
line 3
```

The `sed` script reads a line into the pattern space. The `N` command appends the next line of input to the pattern space with an embedded newline in-between.  The `P` writes the first line up to the newline inserted by `N` in the pattern space. The next cycle starts (no output at the end of the cycle due to the `-n`).

Answer (score 3):

For the error: you need an literal (unbackslashed) newline after the text of a `i` command. In GNU sed you can get away with

```
seq 3 | sed -n -e '/2/{iline1\nline2' -e 'P}'
```

just as you got away with the `\n` for a newline.

Otherwise:

```
seq 3 | sed -n '/2/{i\
line1\
line2
P;}'
```

As to your claims: the `i` command "inserts" into the output file, not into the pattern space. In the corrected example, the pattern space will be 2, which `P` will print in its entirety, since it contains no newline.

Generally, the GNU sed's manpage is a mess, and should only be consulted for the GNU extensions. I recommend the [standard spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), which is much more readable:

```
[1addr]i\
text
       Write text to standard output.
[2addr]P
       Write the pattern space, up to the first <newline>, to standard
       output.
```